# Bootstrap two containers with text and pictures

Tags: css, image, positioning

this is a bit tricky for me working on it for quiet some time, I am not quiet sure how to achieve the following design: Picture "top right" bottom left edge and left bottom top right edge should hit each other.
I think for css/bootstrap veterans it should not be an issue[image: Top left and bottom left some text floating, top right and bottom right picture full size edge on edge]

I am using bootstrap here is my code:

```css
#forth .col-md-6 {
    padding: 0 !important;
    
    
}


/* First subsection styling */
.fourd-paragraph .col-md-6:first-child{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:block;
    left: 6%;
    padding-top:2%;
    
}

.fourd-paragraph .col-md-6:first-child h1 {
    font-size: 34px;
    
}

.fourd-paragraph .col-md-6:first-child p {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-top:3%;
    width: 600px;
    
}


.fourd-paragraph:first-child .col-md-6 .img-responsive {
    float:right;
}


/* second subsection styling */

.left-img  {
    float:left;
    width:100%; 
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    

}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="cold-md-12 third-paragraph">
        <div class="row">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,  nemo                         voluptatum illo molestiae sequi maxime perspiciatis c                     onsectetur nisi l.Nulla facilis voluptatem .</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
 <!-- First subsection of foruth paragraph -->
  <subsection>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
            <div class="cold-md-12 fourd-paragraph">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,  nemo                         voluptatum illo molestiae sequi maxime perspiciatis c                     onsectetur nisi l.Nulla facilis voluptatem 
                    </p>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img             src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/22/23/57/fire-2777580_960_720.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </subsection>

        <!-- Second subsection of paragraph -->
        <subsection>
            <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                         <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/22/23/57/fire-2777580_960_720.jpg" class="img-responsive left-img">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h1> hi from left</h1>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
            </div>


        </subsection>



    
</section>
```

Also I am very thankful for coding improvements. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over your grid, I'd suggest getting into [CSS Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).  Hopefully, this example can show you that you can easily get the grid you're going for.

```css
.text_section {
 background: dodgerblue;
}

/** Define grid names **/
.section_one {
 grid-area: text-one;
}
.section_two {
 grid-area: text-two;
}

.img_one {
 grid-area: img-one;
}
.img_two {
 grid-area: img-two;
}

.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 /** apply grid names here**/
 grid-template-areas:
 "text-one img-one"
 "img-two text-two";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <section class="text_section section_one">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut tempora voluptate, fugit nemo nisi velit aliquid ab? Ab, voluptatibus quas.</p>
 </section>
 <section class="img_section img_one">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-3.jpg" alt="img">
 </section>
 <section class="text_section section_two">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut tempora voluptate, fugit nemo nisi velit aliquid ab? Ab, voluptatibus quas.</p>
 </section>
 <section class="img_section img_two">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-3.jpg" alt="img">
 </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so far, but that is not the correct solution, looks messy.
Maybe I get it with the grid system working. 
But thank you for your help!